# Append Big query table to existing one, by ignoring SCHEMA

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a straight forward question, does Google have a way to append one table to another one, by ignoring SCHEMA as I have the error:

```
Invalid schema update. Field XXXhas changed type from NUMERIC to FLOAT
```

Python code:

```
def COPY():
    client = bigquery.Client()

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.destination = client.dataset("DATASET").table("TABLE")
    #job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
    #job_config._properties['schemaUpdateOptions'] = ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION']

    wave_sql = 'SELECT * FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`'
    wave = client.query(wave_sql,location='EU',job_config=job_config)  
    wave.result()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wave_sql = 'SELECT * REPLACE(CAST(XXXhas AS NUMERIC) AS XXXhas) FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`'
```

note: you will pay for whole table scan, if schema were same you would rather use COPY (instead of SELECT *); also you cannot use `SELECT * EXCEPT() ...` pattern as this will change schema's layout - so you rather should use `SELECT * REPLACE() ...`

Comment: If I will need to cast multiple columns, what will be the best approach?

Comment: For example: how to deal with nested tables: SELECT * 
REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT CAST(OL.Net AS NUMERIC) FROM UNNEST(OrderLines) OL) AS Net)

Comment: Yep )) Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about losing precision, you may change one line of your code to make it work:

```
    wave_sql = 'SELECT * EXCEPT(XXXhas), CAST(XXXhas AS FLOAT64) XXXhas FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try resolving this error by [changing the data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type) of the relevant columns.

For example:

`SELECT
     column_two, column_three, CAST(column_one AS STRING) AS column_one
   FROM
     mydataset.mytable`

and then choose the appropriate table and select "Overwrite"

Comment: are you aware about difference in using COPY vs. SELECT INTO? `COST` is!

Comment: Copy is FREE and select is $5/TB of table size

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @OksanaOk - "directionally" - the answers you already got look to me correct or close to be correct. anyway - if you ask - see my answer below. So, these are more workarounds - As of your "straight forward question" - I think the answer is mostly no ...